# On the second partial derivatives of $g(s,t)=f(2s+3t,3s-2t)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, partial-derivative

Let $f=f(x,y)$ be of class $C^2(\Bbb R^2)$ and $g(s,t)=f(2s+3t,3s-2t)$.

I've correctly found $g_s(s,t)=2f_x(2s+3t,3s-2t)+3f_y(2s+3t,3s-2t)$ and $g_t(s,t)=3f_x(2s+3t,3s-2t)-2f_y(2s+3t,3s-2t)$ but then I'm missing the mixed term in the second ones. Where do the coefficients of $f_{xy}(2s+3t,3s-2t)$ come from?

Comment: From the multivariate Chain Rule applied to $g_s$ or $g_t$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets do $g_{ss}(s,t)$ the remaining second order derivatives are done similarly. First we find (as you already have) that $g_s(s,t)=2f_x(2s+3t,3s-2t)+3f_y(2s+3t,3s-2t)$. Now lets do another derivative wrt. $s$:
\begin{align}
 g_{ss}(s,t) &= \partial_s g_s(s,t) = \partial_s \left( 2f_x(2s+3t,3s-2t)+3f_y(2s+3t,3s-2t) \right) \\
&= 2\left(f_{xx}(2s+3t,3s-2t)\partial_s x +f_{xy}(2s+3t,3s-2t)\partial_s y\right)\\
 &+ 3\left(f_{yx}(2s+3t,3s-2t)\partial_sx + f_{yy}(2s+3t,3s-2t)\partial_sy \right)\\
&= 4f_{xx}(2s+3t,3s-2t)+6f_{xy}(2s+3t,3s-2t)+6f_{yx}(2s+3t,3s-2t)\\
&+9f_{yy}(2s+3t,3s-2t)\\
&=4f_{xx}(2s+3t,3s-2t)+12f_{xy}(2s+3t,3s-2t)+9f_{yy}(2s+3t,3s-2t).
\end{align}
where we have used that $f \in C^2(\mathbb R^2)$ to conclude that $f_{xy}=f_{yx}$.